# Can't access PostgresSQL RDS from ECS using private IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-ecs, vpc

I have a postgres RDS on AWS on Subnet A, VPC 1. I have an ECS service with ASWVPC networking behind a load balancer on subnets A, B, C, VPC 2. Both VPCs are peered. I can't seem to connect to the RDS using its private IP. My ECS containers always try to access the database on its public IP, which is troublesome because I would like to block public access to the RDS. Reachability Analyzer on RDS + Container Elastic Network Interfaces shows that the database is reachable from the container using private IP. Please help!

Edit:
The route table for my ECS service is correct - it points the RDS IP range to the peering connection.

Comment: You haven't provided my info. How exactly do you try to connect to the RDS? What are the exact settings of your VPCs, security groups, route tables? The issue is only with ECS?  Can you cannect from Ec2 instance? Does it work?

Comment: Hi @Marcin, I can connect to the DB if I enable "allow all traffic from all IPs" in my security group for the DB. In the flow logs I can see the ECS instance is trying to connect to the DB on its public IP, not the private IP. I try to connect to the DB using nodejs pg library. Normally I can connect to the DB from my local machine using IP whitelisting.

Comment: My security groups are set to allow all egress from ECS and RDS, and ingress from ECS to RDS (The IP Range of VPC2). The route tables are appropriately pointing to the peering connection.

Comment: Whatever node.js code you have then is trying to use the public IP - can you share your code where it establishes a connection to the database please?

Comment: It sounds like you have "publicly available" enabled on the RDS instance, so it is resolving to a public IP outside of the RDS instance's VPC. If you disable the publicly available setting on the RDS instance it will no longer have a public IP and everything should start resolving correctly to the private IP.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, it's a setting in peering connections - Allow Remote VPC DNS Resolution.

[image]